# How to name "first level" of GeoServer WMS service

Tags: geoserver, wms

I have a GeoServer ImageMosaic layer. When I look at it in Catalog/QGIS Browser the first level is unnamed. How can I name it? The workspace, store and layer are all named in GeoServer...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had no title set under WMS :

[image]